# How to change the DataContext of a button to the parents parent DataContext?

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, datacontext

I have 2 Classes in WPF:

- Meeting
- People

In meeting I have 2 `ObservableCollections`; `AttendingMeeting` and `NotAttendingMeeting` that contain `People` objects

In the xaml the `DataContext` are set to `Meeting`, and I have 2 `DataGrid`s (`AttendingMeeting` and `NotAttendingMeeting`)

I need to add a `Button` to each of the `DataGrid`s to add and remove from `Meeting`, But then I need to change the `DataContext` on the `Button` from e.g.: `AttendingMeeting` to `Meeting`, so that the `Meeting` class can handle the adding and removing `People` from the `ObservableCollection`s.

How can I do this in xaml (changing the `DataContext` from `AttendingMeeting` items to the parents `parent-> Meeting`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're trying to bind to a Command on the Meeting class from within the `DataGrid`:

You can use a `RelativeSource` on your binding to get to the `DataContext` you're interested in. You're markup would look something similar to this:

```
<Grid DataContext="..."> <!-- Assuming a grid is you're layout root and that it's datacontext is the Meeting you spoke of -->
   ...
   <DataGrid ...>
      ...

      <Button Content="Click Me!"
              Command="{Binding Path="DataContext.RemovePersonCommand"
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}}"
              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/> <!-- This would be binding to the current person -->
      ...
   </DataGrid>
   ...
</Grid>
```

You could also use `ElementName` to bind to a parent that has the `DataContext` you're interested in if you're dealing with lots of nesting and a `RelativeSource` would be too complicated.

Comment: Thanks for guiding me into a solution.

This is my working Command Binding:

Command="{Binding ElementName=SelectedMeeting, Path=DataContext.AddPatientsToMeetingCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"

Comment: Personally I'd prefer using ElementName instead of climbing the tree looking for ancestor. This gives a direct reference to the element you want to use instead of relying on the structure not to change in a way that affects your tree climbing (adding another grid at some point between).

Comment: Glad to have helped. @bambuska, I agree...tree climbing is definitely not the best approach, especially when looking for something as common as a Grid.