# Bind datagrid Edit hyperlink to viewmodel in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, binding, mvvm

How do I bind the Edit link in datagrid, I am using following code but cant get the selecteditem to bind to seletcedMember in my viewmodel:

```
<sdk:DataGrid x:Name="MembersListDataGrid" Height="Auto" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Members}" 
                          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedMember, Mode=OneWay}" 
                          AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" IsReadOnly="True">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
       <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                               <Button x:Name="myButton" Content="Edit"   HorizontalAlignment="Center"  
            VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="5" >
                                    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                            <mvvmlightcmd:EventToCommand  
                    Command="{Binding Main.MemberDetailViewCommand, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
                     CommandParameter="{Binding}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" 
                    />
                                        </i:EventTrigger>
                                    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>

                </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    </sdk:DataGrid>
```

and in my view model i have the SelectedMember property:

```
  public Member SelectedMember
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedMember;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_SelectedMember != value)
            {
                _SelectedMember = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedIMember");
            }
        }
    }
```

I step thru the code and it hits my command but the SelectedMember is always null.

Comment: What is MemberDetailViewCommand? Of which type? What is bound to dataContext of DataGrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that with a DataGrid, each column in the DataGrid will have it's context set to a data **member** of the grid's data context.  When you are setting a DataGrid's ItemsSource, you are essentially defining the parent DataContext which will be used as the source for data members for each column.

In your case, the Hyperlink's data context will be not your ViewModel but instead the ItemsSource property of the parent DataGrid (which we cannot see from your code snippet).

You need to either make the command a StaticResource in your XAML or use relative binding to get the DataContext of your parent control.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471643/how-to-change-the-datacontext-of-a-button-to-the-parents-parent-datacontext) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Hi, I edited my code, now i hit the command but having proplem getting the SelectedMember to bind to SelectedItem of the datagrid

Comment: @user282807 - In your RaisePropertyChanged statement, you have an 'I' between 'Selected' and 'Member'.  Try changing it to 'SelectedMember' and seeing if that works.

Comment: Yes I did see it and fixed it but makes no difference.

Comment: for test i put a selectionchanged in code behind and i can see the selecteditem, but i cant get it set in the viewmodel thru xaml binding.

Comment: looks like row selection is interfering with button click, I put a breakpoint on SelectedMember property and instead of clicking the edit button, i just clicked on a row and it hit the breakpoint, the SelectedMember was populated, but again when i click the edit button, the selectedmember goes back to null, is there a way to disable row selection if that's why the SelectedMember is null?

Comment: Try setting the SelectedMember binding mode to "TwoWay".  I noticed you had one way which would be your ViewModel -> View.  You want your View to be able to set the ViewModel.