# Access datacontext of a control's Parent's Parent

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have an xaml like this

```
<Grid>
<Grid.DataContext>
    <bin:ItemsCollViewModel/>
</Grid.DataContext>
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ItemName}" />                            
                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                    <toolkit:ContextMenu >
                        <toolkit:ContextMenu.Items>                                        
                            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Remove" />
                        </toolkit:ContextMenu.Items>
                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
    <controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
        ....
    </controls:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Pivot>
```

I need to bind the command property of the context menu item to an ICommand property(Say TryRemove) in my viewmodel(**ItemsCollViewModel**). This **TryRemove** belongs to **ItemsCollViewModel** .But  the DataContext of its parent(Pivot) is **Items** which is a property in **ItemsCollViewModel**. So how can i bind the command property of this context menu item to a property of its Parent's(Pivot) Parent(Grid).

In short how can i access datacontext of  a control's Parent's Parent.
I got this [How to change the DataContext of a button to the parents parent DataContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471643/how-to-change-the-datacontext-of-a-button-to-the-parents-parent-datacontext)
 but the compiler cannot find **AncestorType={x:Type Grid}**

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding DatContext.TryRemove,  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Grid},AncestorLevel=1}  }"/>
            </ContextMenu>
```

Try AncestorLevel also .I hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks for answering , but as i said in my question compiler cannot find **AncestorType={x:Type Grid}**. I think it is not available in silverlight

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of better late than never:

Add a Name property to your Pivot control and do the following:
`{Binding DataContext.TryRemove, ElementName=MyPivot}`